# hibernate convert two table result with alias as property

Tags: hibernate

when i use hibernate query two tables.

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("select {a.*},{b.*} from a,b where 
a.id=b.id");
query.addEntity("a",A.class);
query.addEntity("b",B.class);
List list = query.list();
```

the list may convert to json as this

```
[
 [{id:1,aa:"aa"},{id:1,"bb":"bb"}],
 [{id:2,aa:"aa2"},{id:2,"bb":"bb2"}]
```

]

can hibernate query list get result like below

```
[
  {
    a:{id:1,aa:"aa"},
    b:{id:1,"bb":"bb"}
 },
  {
    a:{id:2,aa:"aa2"},
    b:{id:2,"bb":"bb2"}
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap result set into some complex POJO and

```
public class ABListPojo{
   private List<ABPojo> abList;
   // ...getters and setters
} 

public class ABPojo{
   private A a;
   private B b;
   // ...getters and setters
}
```

and add setResultTransformer into query

```
query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ABListPojo.class))
```